# Assign a unique 4 digit number to a list of ids using python

Tags: python

I have a list of ids that i want to give a 4 digit unique number for each of them .

For example :

```
driver id = ['5c73d1238472750067e86c6d','5a0d5513494c09001491c118']
unique id = ['1234' , '5897']
```

Is there a package i can use for this?

Comment: If it's a list, you can just give the id that corresponds to the list index (prepend with '000' where needed). E.g., `unique_ids = ['0000', '0001']` in your example.

Comment: You could check https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html

Comment: If a driver id occurs twice or more in the list, does it need to have the same unique id?

Comment: the driver id is unique it will never be duplicated

Comment: Any reason why you (apparently) don't just want to use the index then?

Comment: i was just curious if i can prevent duplication in **random** package

Comment: @K.Amr `random.sample` is usually used to retrieve non-repeating elements from a pool. You can also `random.shuffle` the id pool and keep popping from it.

Comment: Then you should ask about `random`, not about assigning unique IDs. As you can see from comments and answers, these are quite different things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the zfill function of the string object like this

```
ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list(map(lambda x: str(x).zfill(4), ids))
```

And will result in:

```
['0001', '0002', '0003', '0004']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import random
import string

def get_id():
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for n in range(4))
driver_id = [1, 2, 3, 4]
unique_id=[]
while len(unique_id)!=len(driver_id):
    id = get_id()
    if id not in unique_id:
        unique_id.append(id)
print(unique_id)
```

Output:

```
['7518', '7806', '4654', '0677']
```

Comment: is there a chance that the output contains duplicate values?

Comment: While this is unlikely, there is still a 1 in 1000 chance you’ll get the same number as an existing ID.

Comment: is there a way i can make sure it wont be duplicated ?

Comment: Math time! How many numbers do you need to be 90% guaranteed you have at least one duplicate number?

Comment: the list of ids i have in an excel sheet is more than 7000

Comment: @K.Amr I have edit answer it would always give you a unique id.

Comment: Complexity is O(N^2) for every number traverses the ```list``` driver_id

Comment: yes @drd you are right but it depends what type of program you are writing if it is mentioned then we might consider otherwise it is ok to go with this solution

Comment: if i have a data set of 1 million id, whats the range  number i should i add? @VashdevHeerani

Comment: @K.Amr for one million ids you have to increase to six-digit instead of four-digit id

Answer (score -1):

Most of the answers are on *how* to generate them, assuming 4 digit number are used as `string`. 
Let us examine the problem and come up with design, constraints and manage them.

If you are using numbers as numbers, not strings, then non zero numbers starting with non zero(s) are,
1000 to 9999, you can only address 8999 elements (drivers in your case). -***Constraint***

Example:  If you consider *0123*  as a *number* is actually 3 digit number, *123*.

***Design:***

Generate the numbers in a for loop using `range(1000,10000)` and keep them in a list(code below): 
**Complexity** : is constant O(c), happens only once.

```
>>>
>>> four_digit_pool = []
>>> for i in range(1000, 10000):
...     four_digit_pool.append(i)
...
>>>
```

```
four_digit_pool = [1000, 1001, ..., 9999]
```

when you encounter a an element, look up if key exists and add it to driver_id_map.

Add it to map and pop element from list (pool of ids). Do not use remove, use pop, pop is ALWAYS O(1). 
Note: In this case remove also is O(1), because it is sorted and you are removing from left one by one. But use pop, for surety.

```
driver_id_map = {
1000 : '5c73d1238472750067e86c6d'
1001 : '5a0d5513494c09001491c118'
...
}
```

You can also have above map reversed, if you want to look-up if driver is already in list.

```
driver_id_map = {
'5c73d1238472750067e86c6d' : 1000
'5a0d5513494c09001491c118' : 1001
...
}
```

Look-up is **O(1)** for maps.

If you loop through all drivers and assign it, Complexity is O(N)

**Note:** 
If you are using numbers as strings and considering non zero numbers which are starting with zero(s) are 1108 numbers. You get additional ~1000 more drivers can be addressed.

These numbers also get into the four_digit_pool. Complexity won't change much.

numbers starting with 0 - 999 possibilities, example: 0123

numbers starting with 00 - 99 possibilities, example: 0023

numbers starting with 000 - 9 possibilities, example: 0003

numbers starting with 0000 - 1 possibilities, example: 0000 (the only one)